# Why am I not receiving COM events via Com4J?

Tags: java, events, com, com4j

I am using Com4J to interact with Microsoft Outlook. I have generated the Java type definitions as per the [Com4J tutorial](https://com4j.dev.java.net/tutorial.html). Here is an example of some code that waits for the user to close an email.

```
// Registers my event handler
mailItem.advise(
        ItemEvents.class,
        new ItemEvents() {
            @Override
            public void close(Holder<Boolean> cancel) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.close(cancel);
                System.out.println("Closed");
            }
        }
    );

// Displays the email to the user
mailItem.display();
```

This code successfully displays the email to the user. Unfortunately, my program never prints `"Closed"` when the user closes the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Com4J generates an event class (`ItemEvents` in my scenario), the default behavior for all generated methods is to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` (see the `com4j.tlbimp.EventInterfaceGenerator` class for details).

For example, here is the `close` method of the `ItemEvents` class that my anonymous class overrides:

```
@DISPID(61444)
public void close(Holder<Boolean> cancel) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Therefore, when my anonymous class calls `super.close(cancel);`, the parent class throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, preventing execution from reaching my `System.out.println("Closed");` statement. Therefore, my anonymous class should *really* have looked like this:

```
mailItem.advise(
        ItemEvents.class,
        new ItemEvents() {
            @Override
            public void close(Holder<Boolean> cancel) {
                System.out.println("Closed");
            }
        }
    );
```

What surprised me is that Com4J appears to have simply *ignored* the `UnsupportedOperationException` thrown from the event handler altogether, leaving me no indication of what actually happened. I wrote this code to demonstrate:

```
mailItem.advise(
        ItemEvents.class,
        new ItemEvents() {
            @Override
            public void close(Holder<Boolean> cancel) {
                System.out.println("Getting ready to throw the exception...");
                throw new RuntimeException("ERROR! ERROR!");
            }
        }
    );
```

The program emits this output:

```
Getting ready to throw the exception...
```

However, there is no indication that a `RuntimeException` was ever thrown.